# How to run the following exports: Customer Base and Customer Addresses?

Tags: customer-address

A company is switching one of my Magento 2 websites to Shopify (or some system like that) and they asked the following:

We were unable to run the following exports.  Can you please provide them?

```
Customer Base
Customer Addresses
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What is that? Specifically, what is customer base - what is that referring to?
2. How can I provide those exports to them? Is it via Magento Admin or MySQL?

Exact steps would be very much appreciated.

---

---

UPDATED on May 19th, 2023:

*I am now able to download these 4 Exports from:*

```
- System - Data Transfer - Export:

Advanced Pricing
Products
Stock sources
Customer main file
```

but trying to export the following:

Customer addresses

Gives these Errors:

in **Magento Admin:**

```
Please correct the data sent value.
```

in **exception.log:**

```
[2023-05-19 20:12:50] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

I have created the following post about this problem:

["Please correct the data sent value." Error WHEN exporting 'Customer Addresses'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367037/please-correct-the-data-sent-value-error-when-exporting-customer-addresses)

Answer (score 2):

**Magento Admin:**

1. Log in to your Magento 2 admin panel.
2. Navigate to the menu on the left side and click on "System".
3. Under the "Data Transfer" section, click on "Export".
4. On the Export page, you will find various export options. Select
   "Customers Main File" to export the Customer Base and "Customer
   Addresses" to export the Customer Addresses.
5. After selecting the desired export option, click on the "Continue"
   button.
6. On the Export Settings page, you can specify the export file format,
   entity attributes, and other export settings according to your
   requirements.
7. Once you have configured the export settings, click on the
   "Continue" button.
8. Magento will generate the export file based on your settings and
   provide you with a download link. Click on the link to download the
   export file to your local computer.

That's it! You have successfully exported the Customer Base and Customer Addresses in Magento 2. Make sure to check the exported file to ensure that it contains the desired data.

Comment: "Customer Main File" works but when I do "Customer Addresses" - it says: 'Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon. Make sure your cron job is running to export the file' but no file is ever generated. Why is that and how to fix?

Comment: I am able to download all except for the 'Customer addresses' export. I have created a new post about that issue if you be able to help please? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367037/please-correct-the-data-sent-value-error-when-exporting-customer-addresses

Answer (score 1):

You can export these two tables from database:

customer_entity

customer_address_entity

Comment: Thank you for that. Am I able to do that via phpMyAdmin? Would you please tell me how? Thank you.

Comment: You can do that with phpMyAdmin 
1- navigate with your database of magento
2- In checkbox select customer_entity and customer_address_entity
3- At the end of the tables you will find dropdown menu has "with Selected:"
4- Click it and choose Export
5- You will be navigated to export page click Export

You are done you will get the two tables with SQL format.