# "Please correct the data sent value." Error WHEN exporting 'Customer Addresses'

Tags: export

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
```

In:

```
- System - Data Transfer - Export:
```

The following 3 exports work without any problems:

```
Advanced Pricing
Products
Stock sources
```

While these 2 did not:

```
Customer main file
Customer addresses
```

I have done the following as suggested here:

[Magento 2.3.2 Product Export Message: "Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295935/magento-2-3-2-product-export-message-message-is-added-to-queue-wait-to-get-yo)

```
(the post from Rakesh Donga)
```

and now, instead of waiting for the cron to run, the file just drops down (gets downloaded) right away BUT only for the same 3 exports listed above.

For these 2, it was giving the following Error:

```
Customer main file
Customer addresses

Please correct the data sent value.
```

I have resolved this (made it work) for the Customer main file by excluding these 3 fields:

```
Failures Number
First Failure Date
Failures Number
```

So now, I just need to export 'Customer Addresses'. Trying to do that gives the same Error:

***Please correct the data sent value.***

even if I exclude all possible fields!

I googled this and one of the suggestions was to increase memory_limit to at least 1024M and max_execution_time to at least 18000.

I contacted my hosting company and they said:

*The PHP memory limit was already set to 2048 M (2 GB), so I only increased the max_execution_time to '18000' as requested.*

I deleted the contents of the var/log folder and then tried to export Customer addresses again, then downloaded the log files:

**exception.log:**

```
[2023-05-19 20:12:50] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

**debug.log:**

```
[2023-05-19 20:12:50] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amasty.rewards.highlight.container' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.form.content', but their parents are different: 'alert.urls' and 'product.info' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amasty.rewards.highlight.container' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.form.content', but their parents are different: 'alert.urls' and 'product.info' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.DEBUG: URI '/index.php/wishlist/index/add/product/1054/form_key/VNRFsK319NvQ5tjK/5280flowersdelivery'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add) [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
```

**system.log:**

```
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amasty.rewards.highlight.container' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.form.content', but their parents are different: 'alert.urls' and 'product.info' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:51] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:12:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amasty.rewards.highlight.container' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.form.content', but their parents are different: 'alert.urls' and 'product.info' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-05-19 20:13:07] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
```

**How to fix this and is there a way to pull this out of the database in the mean time? And if so, how to do that in phpMyAdmin?**